# What to do with questions where dev/user posts (or seem to post) requirements instead of question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, best-practices

I have seen many questions (specially here in Magento SE) that seem that user has not put any effort in the question itself and just posted the requirements from the project/ assigned task here.

What to do with these kind of questions? Should I flag them too broad and ask user to post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those type of questions we vote for close directly as too broad/ unclear what you are asking

In your case you can flag and mentioned should be closed and select any of the reason or you can give your own reason in others

Other user who has close votes right will close the question if they agree what you say.